# Motionlayout with bottom sheet dosn't work as expected

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-motionlayout, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to achieve this animation from [this tutorial](https://riggaroo.dev/android-motionlayout-tutorial-collapsing-view/) but the difference that this tutorial is doing with recycler view but I want to achieve it with bottom sheet

[image: scrolling image]

here is my layout of what I'm doing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewAvatar"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_reaction_24"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_view_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="90dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <View
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvHorzinatal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_rv" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Swipe Up"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_rv" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

and here is my scene layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="1000">

    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:touchAnchorId="@+id/bottomSheet"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
    <KeyFrameSet />
</Transition>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"></ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
        android:id="@id/imageViewAvatar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

but whenever I put Onswipe on the coordinate layout or the constraint inside it it's dosn't work how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

CoordinatorLayout is a system for animating motion of views in relation to with NestedScrollview(RecyclerView)
MotionLayout can be used for the same thing.

you have two choices:

- Use only one - MotionLayout is a little more flexible, CoordnatorLayout provides standard interactions.
- Make MotionLayout the child to animate only the top panel. CoordnatorLayout does the overall animation.

There are some examples of both [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples#coordinatorlayout_12)